# Updating prometheus rules

Tags: prometheus

I make PUT {prometheus_url}/v2/rules?slug={slug} to change rules configuration, but in the response body I get not updated rules configuration.
Why didn't it change?

Or do you know some another way to update alert rules?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that it is not a supported method.

Do you have documentation supporting this method/verb?

The only API documentation I find is [HTTP API](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#rules) and that only documents `/v1` and only a `GET` on `/rules`.

This makes sense since rules are (currently?) statically configured via [`rules_files`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/#configuring-rules).

If possible, revising them via the API would only persist until the server were restarted.